# Let $a_{n} \in \mathbb N $ be a sequence and $a_{n}\rightarrow +\infty$. Which of the following sentences is correct.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I have my sequence $a_{n} \in \mathbb N $ and $a_{n}\rightarrow +\infty$. I have two statements and only one of them is correct:

---

a) $a_{a_{n}}$ is bounded from below

b) the sequence $b_{n}=$ inf {$a_{k}:n\leq k$} is bounded.

---

So the correct answer would be $a)$ according to our textbook, but i am not quite sure why and especially why is $b$ incorrect.

I would have chosen $b)$ with the argument that since the Infimum is unique and only one then the sequence $b_{n}$ would be constand and therefore bounded.

What would be wrong with my logic and also why would $a)$ be correct? I would assume it follows from the fact that $a_{n}$ is bounded since it is a sequence of natural numbers, but how so.

I would be really thankful for an answer,

Annalisa

Comment: For b) try $a_n=n$,what is $b_n$? Is it bounded?

Comment: b) would have been true if it was $k \le n$ instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding a).**

If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, you have $a_n >0$ for $n$ large enough. Let's say for $n \ge N$. Hence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded below by $\min(0, a_1, \dots, a_N)$.

**Regarding b).**

Take $a_n = n$. You have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ and $b_n = n$ also. Hence $\{b_n\}$ is not bounded.

**Finally,** regarding your comment: *I would have chosen $b)$ with the argument that since the Infimum is unique and only one then the sequence $b_{n}$ would be constant and therefore bounded.*

You're right that $\inf \{a_{k}:n\leq k\}$ is unique for a set in general. But here, you have to notice that the set $\{a_{k}:n\leq k\}$ depends on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For b) consider the example $a_n=n$. In this case $b_n=n$ and $(b_n)$ is not bounded.

For a) note that there exits $n_0$ such that  $a_n >0$ for $n \geq n_0$. Let $c$ be the minimum of $0$ and the numbers $a_1,a_2,,..., a_{n_0}$. Then $a_n \geq c$ for all $n$ so $(a_n)$ is bounded from below.